# When should CAS (Code Access Security) be used extensively and with great conscientiousness?

Tags: .net, code-access-security

I'm reading a lot about CAS but it seems that the book is advocating some very granular control using CAS, even going to the length of suggesting that you should fine-tune CAS restrictions on *portions of methods* that require more or less security than the rest of the method.

This is great, but it could be very time consuming and fraught with the potential to get yourself into a CAS permissions quagmire ("WHY isn't this code running!!!")

My intuition tells me to only use CAS restrictions when your application is accessing system resources. Is this enough? Are there other "rule-of-thumb" guidelines for when to use CAS restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are reading up to date material - CAS has changed significantly in 4.0. With the exception of things like principal permissions, it is pretty much deprecated, except within specific hosts like IE.

So: I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. I am studying for 70-536 so that's why I am deep into it. I will read the newer material after I take the exam.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the .NET 4.0 CAS changes, CAS permission demands are still pertinent, but mainly for API/framework developers, which was pretty much their intended user even way back when.  Unfortunately, the docs (including the exam prep materials) don't make a very clear distinction between CAS stuff that is relevant to API devs vs application devs.  Most application devs should never (or at least very, very rarely) need to write a permission demand other than for a PrincipalPermission (which isn't really a CAS permission) in any version of the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CAS, you may want to take a look at object capabilities. If you design your code with ocaps discipline, it shouldn't be hindered by any CAS restriction you set up.

- [Object-capability model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-capability_model)
- [Some YoutTube videos about ocaps concepts and implementations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UH66YrzT-_M&playnext=1&list=PL35C4E5A0FC5008FB)